# Erro com o fetch_assoc, como faço para corrigir? O echo não retorna valor desejado

Tags: php

Eu tenho seguinte código que estou aprendendo:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ordem_producao WHERE op_id = $id;";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
$resultado = $query->fetch_assoc($sql);
```

no `body` do meu html eu  tenho:

```
<?php echo $resultado['id']; ?>
```

na página aparece seguinte erro

**PHP Warning:  mysqli_result::fetch_assoc() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in E:\home\paginas\view\view_op.php on line 9**

a linha 9 está o código

```
$resultado = $query->fetch_assoc($sql);
```

O que estou fazendo de errado??

Obrigado

Comment: Nenhuma das respostas foi útil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa de parâmetros em `fetch_assoc()`
Você pode fazer assim:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM times WHERE id = $id;";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Nome: " . $row["nome"]. "<br>";
}
```

*Basta você remover o parametro de `fetch_assoc()`*

Comment: Obrigado vou testar aqui. Valeu mesmo

Comment: Então dá certo mas o que está dentro do htmi aparece em branco

Comment: Nessa caso não foi selecionado nenhuma linha. Verifique o nome da tabela, condição where, e os campos que esta exibindo.

Comment: Entendi vou por partes aqui para ver o que pode estar dando errado.

Answer (score 1):

Para associar todo o resultado da query, você deve utilizar o método [`fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ordem_producao WHERE op_id = $id;";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);


//Retorna o resultado da query em um array associativo
$resultado = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//Retorna o resultado da query em um array numérico
$resultado = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_NUM);

//Retorna o resultado da query em um array com ambos os tipos(associativo e numérico)
$resultado = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, vou testar aqui